# Comparison of Oracle UCP, C3P0 and HikariCP

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, c3p0, hikaricp, ucp

I am trying to compare Some of the java connection pool libraries, but so far I've not found any satisfactory answer. 
Right now C3P0 is being used in my application but I want to suggest other Connection Pool libraries but I don't have any solid information to migrate to any other connection pool mechanism. I read that Oracle's UCP is using Connection Harvesting mechanism but I don't know how useful it is and does any other provider also providing Harvesting mechanism. 
What are the points can be included to compare the various Connection Pooling mechanism.
Can anyone please suggest me which one is better among Oracle UCP, C3P0 and HikariCP?
Is there any other mechanism available better than above 3?

Answer (score 5):

The 12.2.0.1 version of UCP ([download here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-ucp-122-3110062.html)) has a non-blocking architecture that was explained in a session at JavaOne and which makes it very scalable. You can have thousands of threads that share the same UCP pool and won't run into any scalability issue in the pool (of course you may run out of connections but that's another problem).

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, connection harvesting is anti pattern.
Generally, it is better to release resource asap after use, especially db connections (think of locks and concurrent users)
If you have no 'specific' to oracle or web server constraints, HikariCP is good option. why it is good ? check their site and wiki.

Comment: Thank you very much Nitin. 
Can you please suggest me some Connection Pooling tutorials which give deep insight of Connection Pooling execution/working.